# Why do I see no photos on my film?

Tags: old-cameras

I've got Smiena 8m. I have put ISO100 film in it and it appears that there are no photos on that film (I have checked it in /almost/ darkness). What might be the problem?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45773/how-to-tell-if-a-film-camera-is-actually-making-shots

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are unwinding part of the roll before you have it developed to check the images. The term here is "latent image." There is a chemical change in the film when light strikes it, but it has to go through a development process (a series of chemical baths) to make the image visible (normally, Wikipedia has an example of a visible latent image, but exposure was unusual).

I hate to say this but "almost darkness" also might be enough to obscure part of those latent images. Sorry, if that is the case.